# NullInjectorError: No provider for Compiler

Tags: angular

Self-answered question for this error:

injector.ts:128 Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError[Compiler]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Compiler]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Compiler!
    at _NullInjector.get (injector.ts:23) [angular]

Answer (score 20):

I had forgotten to import `BrowserModule` into my main app module.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,  // <-- this!
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If you only see this error during unit testing, see this question:
[Error: No provider for Compiler! DI Exception Angular 2 Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470128/error-no-provider-for-compiler-di-exception-angular-2-testing)